# Using command line arguments to read specific column from the data file in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
          0   0.258  -0.188  -0.446  -0.035   0.351  -0.317   1.361   1.066   1.198   1.115   1.208   0.804  -0.084  -0.643   0.201
          1   0.265  -0.193  -0.457  -0.036   0.361  -0.325   1.361   1.068   1.197   1.113   1.208   0.803  -0.082  -0.653   0.202
          2   0.264  -0.190  -0.453  -0.037   0.358  -0.322   1.363   1.070   1.200   1.115   1.212   0.806  -0.080  -0.658   0.201
          3   0.264  -0.182  -0.446  -0.041   0.354  -0.314   1.363   1.073   1.200   1.113   1.212   0.806  -0.082  -0.659   0.198
          4   0.257  -0.180  -0.436  -0.038   0.346  -0.308   1.359   1.067   1.198   1.111   1.208   0.802  -0.084  -0.655   0.194
          5   0.260  -0.176  -0.436  -0.042   0.348  -0.306   1.357   1.065   1.193   1.109   1.204   0.801  -0.083  -0.648   0.193
```

I want to read only a specific column, say the third column from this file using a command line argument (probably `getarg`). Thus, I if user wants to read only a particular column from the data file, he/she should be able to pass that as an argument to the command that runs the executable. As of now, I am simply reading the whole data in a big multidimensional array and then discarding the unwanted columns. However, since the file is too big, this is consuming a lot of memory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want to write that column to a file, or do you want to store it in an array, or  what do you intend to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible solution is to read data file line by line and store required column in allocated array. Anyway, in case when source data is too large, it always better to store temporary values in dynamically allocated variables and return memory (deallocate variables) as soon as they no longer required.

Following example shows how this can be achieved. It reads source file and prints specified column to console.

```
program read_columns

    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: iostat_end
    implicit none

    ! array to store one source line
    real, dimension(16) :: array

    character(len=16) :: buffer

    integer unit
    integer status
    integer column

    ! suppose we have only one command line argument
    if (command_argument_count() >= 1) then
        call get_command_argument(1, buffer)
        write (*,*) buffer
        read (buffer, '(i)') column
    end if

    open(newunit = unit, file = 'big_table.txt', status = 'old', action = 'read')
    do
        read(unit, *, iostat = status) array
        if (status == iostat_end) then
            exit
        end if

        if (status > 0) then
            error stop 'Could not read a file.'
        end if

        ! fifth column to print
        write(*, '(f8.3)') array(column)
    end do

    close(unit)
end
```

Comment: The main point is that the user should be able to pass the number of the column to be read to the runtime using something like `getarg`. I don't see that in your answer.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar That is a small detail you can append yourself easily. This is not service for supplying fully working  software for you. If you downvote such an answer under your own question it is just ingratitude.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF! In this answer I only wanted to show how it's possible to read and process a large array. By the way, I have added a block that expects and reads exactly one command line arguments.

Comment: [@syscreat `read(buffer,*) column` might be better than `read(buffer,'(i)') column` because gfortran complained that "Nonnegative width required..."]

Comment: @VladimirF: The answer given here is not answer to the question I am asking. I think I very well understand that the StackOverflow is not the service provider.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar I completely disagree. Now it is exactly what you asked and even before it was everything you really needed.

Comment: The answer is a good answer for the question you asked. If this answer doesn't fit your need, let me submit that it's not the answer that's wrong.